# Fix an image in the middle of the page with HTML

Tags: css, html

I normally do not deal with HTML and I thought that should be pretty easy but seems that it is not. All I wanted was an image and some text displayed in the middle of the page. I can align the image and text to the middle horizontally but I cannot vertically. I finally found a solution and I wondered why this is working and if there is any better way.

Code Version 1 (not working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png"
        style="float:middle">
        <br>
        Hello World!
     </div>    
   </body> 
 </html>
```

Although I read to only use tables when it is a table I tried:

Code Version 2 (not working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <body>
  <table width="100%" border="0" height="100%" align="CENTER">
    <tr><td align="CENTER">  
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png"
        style="float:middle">
        <br>
        Hello World!
    </td></tr> 
     </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Code Version 3 (working, why?):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table width="100%" border="0" height="100%" align="CENTER">
    <tr><td align="CENTER">  
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/fc0/000000.png"
        style="float:middle">
        <br>
        Hello World!
    </td></tr> 
     </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle? It'll make it user for everyone to help :) http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's kind of irrelevant: but you should do your styling externally, and the `border` attribute for tables is deprecated.

Comment: There's also no such rule as "float:middle"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a good approach to centre vertically and horizontally.

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/demo.html

Comment: Perfect. That is doing the trick. It actually is just the  style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;". More is not needed. http://jsfiddle.net/hol42/wq6pC/2/

Answer (score 1):

Set a width for your image and use:

```
<img width:"900px" style="margin:0 auto">
```

it means 0 margin from top and bottom and auto from both sides.

Edit: Don't use tables. just use this:

```
<div style="width:900px;margin:0 auto">
<img width:"900px">
your text
</div>
```

if you want to put the whole thing in the middle.

Comment: Btw, you're <div> will never center.

Comment: Sorry, does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/hol42/WwDBR/1/ Now the image is on the top left corner. But I want it in the middle both ways.

Comment: mine is in the middle. what browser are u using?

Comment: @Brian the div is in the middle: jsfiddle.net/hol42/WwDBR/1

Comment: FireFox, and also in JSFiddle. top left in both.

Comment: Thats really odd ! I see it in Chrome and FireFox in the middle !!

Comment: Middle AND center is needed. Not just middle top. I tested on IE/Windows and Chrome/Mac. Both not working.

Answer (score 0):

The third version doesn't have a doctype declaration, which in most browsers triggers "[quirks mode](http://gutfeldt.ch/matthias/articles/doctypeswitch.html)". This means that they don't follow the specs as closely as they do in "standards mode", which results in the behaviour you're seeing. While it may be what you're trying to get, it's not technically correct.

In short, there is no *standard* way to centre something vertically in HTML/CSS.